# Job gets executed twice at the same time by redis rq worker

Tags: python, redis, queue, rq

The version of my `redis is 4.1.2`, `rq is 1.10.1`
I use supervisor to create 5 workers at most like below:

```
command=rq worker --with-scheduler -P /myworker_path -c settings high default low
numprocs=5
```

All of my jobs go to default queue currently. Most of the time, job is executed once as expected.
But sometimes, I found some jobs were executed twice at the same second.

I'm new to use RQ and still learning. Is it the right way I use the rq worker? 

What I want to do is to use 5 workers to process the same queue to improve the scalability of my tool.